# Write text like insert key is pressed on UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to replicate the functionality of pressing the INS button (characters next to the cursor get replaced when typing) in an IOS UITextField? Also how to move the cursor to the start of the uitextfield?

For moving the cursor I tried those, but it doesn't move to the start:

```
1) func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let newPosition = textField.beginningOfDocument
    textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
    return true
 }

2) @IBAction func textEditingDidBegin(_ sender: UITextField) {
      let newPosition = sender.beginningOfDocument
      sender.selectedTextRange = sender.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please put each issue in a seperate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement 'insert' functionality, you can use the following in your UITextFieldDelegate. In case there is not a single character to replace after the cursor (or multiple characters are selected), the default behaviour is invoked. Make sure to disable autocapitalisation (`.autocapitalizationType = .none`), otherwise inserting text when starting ay the beginning will be all capitals.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
               shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard
        range.length == 0,        // no text is selected
        string.count == 1,        // typing (or pasting) a single character
        let selectedRange = textField.selectedTextRange,
        let end = textField.position(from: selectedRange.start, offset: 1)
    else { return true }
    
    if let newRange = textField.textRange(from: selectedRange.start, to: end) {
        textField.replace(newRange, withText: string)
        return false
    }
    
    return true
}
```

To set the cursor at the beginning you can use the following. Unfortunately there is a slight glitch where you can see the cursor moving from the end to the begin when you start editing.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let begin = textField.beginningOfDocument
    guard
        let range = textField.textRange(from: begin, to: begin)
    else { return }
    
    // delay setting the position to prevent it from being overwritten
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        textField.selectedTextRange = range
    }
}
```